# SQL - conditionally set column values to NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table - `some_table` which has a number of columns and some of them have some invalid value in some rows which need to transformed into `NULL`.

I cannot use the below due as mutating the original table is not allowed by permissions for one and also it needs to be repeated for all column names.

```
UPDATE some_table TABLE@@ SET column_name = NULL WHERE column_name = 'invalid value';
```

So it needs to be a 'SELECT' operation to create a new table with invalid values converted to `NULL` - is there a quick way to do this ?

**Updating with an answer from @Jonny below**

`NULLIF` is a good option. However is there a way to apply it to all columns rather having to do it for each column separately - sometimes the number of columns is pretty huge.

Comment: dude,you can't apply it to all columns. Johnny's answer is good, you have to deal with it 1 column by 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a NULLIF

Have a look at 9.16.3. NULLIF
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

```
SELECT NULLIF('invalid value', column_name)
FROM some_table
```

Comment: NULLIF is a good option. However is there a way to apply it to all column rather having to do it for each column seperately?

Comment: Please do not link to outdated versions of Postgres manual. Use `/docs/current/` for current version of the manual.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
INSERT INTO some_table2 (column_name, ...) SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE column_name <> 'invalid value';
INSERT INTO some_table2 (column_name, ...) SELECT null, ... FROM some_table WHERE column_name = 'invalid_value';
```